# How to disable dnsmasq?

Tags: linux-mint, dnsmasq

From time to time when I'm switching from `eth0` to `wlan0` (or vice versa) interface domain name resolving breaks and `/etc/resolv.conf` contains

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I commented `#dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and restarted network manager with `restart network-manager`. But this didn't help.

Then I found that `dnsmasq` process is not a child of NetworkManager

```
# pstree -spu $(pidof dnsmasq)
init(1)───dnsmasq(3015,libvirt-dnsmasq)
```

I'm not sure why it is running. Can it be related to VirtualBox?
I don't want it to touch `resolve.conf`. How to disable it?

My system is Linux Mint 17 Qiana.

Comment: Disabling dnsmasq is unlikely to help you: its strong point is to make this work automatically in most cases.

Comment: That is exactly what I want: each time I'm switching between interfaces or between networks/routers it to work without manual corrections. Let's assume that `dnsmasq` is a good software and it knows why it overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf` content with `nameserver 127.0.1.1` value. So why it doesn't do its job then?

Comment: With dnsmasq, `/etc/resolv.conf` should always contain `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, because it handles all DNS requests. With NetworkManager+dnsmasq, what normally happens is that NM sends messages to dnsmasq over dbus to tell it when connections change. Why isn't it doing it? That's a question you could ask on this site — with all necessary explanations about your network setup.

Comment: Can you please then just let me know why it is `127.0.1.1` (not `127.0.0.1`) and where it is configured?

Comment: Anything beginning with `127.` points to the local machine. I don't know why  127.0.1.1 is used here. Anyway, if you want help with dnsmasq, you need to ask a new question where you explain your setup, including why VirtualBox is involved at all (is your system running in a VM? Or is it a VM host? What kind of VM configurations have you made? etc.).

Comment: Actually dnsmasq failed to start by default configuration on Linux mint 17 when I installed it.And I removed dnsmasq from linux mint 17

Comment: Same problem for me, had to disable dnsmasq on my virtualbox vm otherwise it would fail from time to time.

Answer (score 19):

On Linux Mint, dnsmasq is installed to cache DNS queries, and thereby speed up your Internet experience.  The first part of disabling it is to change the configuration in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` by commenting out `dns=dnsmasq`.

```
sudo sed -i 's/^dns=dnsmasq/#&/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Next, you have to restart both the `network-manager` and `networking` services.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
```

Since my laptop is really tight on RAM, I made sure the dnsmasq service stopped.  For some reason, this wasn't done automatically with the service restarts.  I suspect there was a more elegant way to stop it than this, but I got tired of looking when I couldn't find an init file and SIGHUP didn't work.

```
sudo killall dnsmasq
```

Personally, I had to disable dnsmasq because network manager and dnsmasq don't like me wiring in a second connection to an otherwise disconnected router.

Comment: Small warning: restarting `network-manager` causes the Cinnamon desktop to crash into fallback mode. Be sure to save your work!